huggingface_hub.utils._errors.LocalEntryNotFoundError
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pangchongwen/anaconda3/envs/chatglm3/bin/huggingface-cli", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/pangchongwen/anaconda3/envs/chatglm3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/commands/huggingface_cli.py", line 49, in main
service.run()
File "/home/pangchongwen/anaconda3/envs/chatglm3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/commands/download.py", line 160, in run
print(self._download())  # Print path to downloaded files
File "/home/pangchongwen/anaconda3/envs/chatglm3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/commands/download.py", line 201, in _download
return snapshot_download(
File "/home/pangchongwen/anaconda3/envs/chatglm3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pangchongwen/anaconda3/envs/chatglm3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/_snapshot_download.py", line 251, in snapshot_download
raise LocalEntryNotFoundError(
huggingface_hub.utils._errors.LocalEntryNotFoundError: An error happened while trying to locate the files on the Hub and we cannot find the appropriate snapshot folder for the specified revision on the local disk. Please check your internet connection and try again.
I suspect it is because I deleted the cache of huggingface in the .cache folder, and then this problem occurred. I don’t know how to solve it. How to restore the cache directory structure of huggingface?
I guess it's not a network problem
